# How can I refresh list of elements called using BLoC pattern managed in separate Stateful Widget?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

[image]

I've a kind of scenario as displayed in this image. Where in a single screen Post information and comments on that posts are being displayed. Also one can add comment by clicking plus icon and add a new comment.

My Screen Structure is as below:

- PostDetail

  - PostInfoScreen
  - PostCommentListScreen (This is paginated API call implemented with BLoC Pattern)
  - PostAddNewCommentScreen

Now, the trouble that I'm facing is related to refresh this comment listing when a user add a new comment. (i.e. Initially, 10 comments are there and If I'm adding a new comment from PostAddNewCommentScreen and I move back to PostInfoScreen, comment list from PostCommentListScreen should get refreshed to get newly added comment & one count incremented to previous total count)

What I'm facing is, BLoC for fetching comment list is created in PostCommentListScreen with passed Post id to get comment list. While coming back to PostInfoScreen after adding a new comment how can I add Event to PostCommentListScreen BLoC to make a fresh API call to updated list of comments.

Comment: You can use BlocBuilder for that.
Can you show your widget part with code, please?

Comment: @dubace Yes I've already made use of that. My actual programming scenario is for client app so can't share code here. But yeah now I solved this thing using `MultiBlocProvider` on `PostDetail` screen.
Hence now I can create an instance of `BLoC` attached to `PostCommentListScreen` inside `PostDetail` screen and add refresh list event when I add a new comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone who is facing same issue like I've face, below is the solution.

- Use `MultiBlocProvider` at `PostDetail` screen and create `BLoC` using `BlocProvider` for `PostCommentListScreen` along with `BLoC` of `PostInfoScreen` if it's there. (In my scenario I've multiple `BLoC` to provide).
- On `PostDetail`, declare an instance of `PostInfoScreenBloc` and `PostCommentListScreenBloc` and attache it to available `BLoC` provided from above using `BlocProvider.of<T>(context)`.
- We can use the instance of `PostCommentListScreenBloc` to add an event to refresh comment list and get the latest data.

Remember this is only for the scenario where we have a Part of a screen (in my case comment list) in separate `StatefulWidget` having its own `BLoC`.